# How to use CoreML model output MLMultiArray

Tags: swift, coreml, coremltools

I need to parse the results in the output of prediction from a CoreML model.

I can see that the type of output is MLMultiArray, but when I use the type within my code like this:

`let a = MultiArray<Float>(result.transpose_1_tmp_0)`

It always throws an error:

> Cannot find 'MultiArray' in scope

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiArray is not a built-in datatype. Use the variable name:

```
var result: MLMultiArray //Your populated array
let a = result[[z, y, x] as [NSNumber]].floatValue
```

Also you might want to check out [Swiftier MultiArray](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/Docs/SwiftyMultiArray.markdown). Follow the [CoreMLHelpers](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers) install instructions.

EDIT:

`MLMultiArray` is part of the `CoreML` framework. To use it, you must import the framework like this:

```
import CoreML
```

Comment: thanks @Jeshua, I cannot even use `MLMultiArray`, it throws me an error saying `Cannot find 'MLMultiArray' in scope.`  do you know why?? Am I missing any package??

Comment: also here is another question I asked if you are interested in answering it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731473/coreml-compiler-error-espresso-exception-invalid-blob-shape-cannot-broadcas  many thanks

Comment: Please see the edit. Let me know if you still cannot use it.

Comment: thanks @Jeshua, it works~! So happy about it after days of searching. Btw, do we have a way to manipulate the values in the `MLMultiArray` like what we can do in Python with Numpy?

Comment: Glad I could help. Not sure about your other SO post, I guess it's a bug with `coremltools`. For stuff you can do with them, such as transpose, check out the Swiftier MultiArray link in my answer.